# regular expression to match delimited substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like this

```
var test = 'Hello you have multiple L2:Me here;L3:Me not here; and some other text...';
```

I want to get string  array

```
L2:Me here    
L3:Me not here
```

The format is L(some number):text;

What will be regex?

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know regular expressions, here is a good source to learn it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Please go through the basics of RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those semicolons are always going to be there, you can use something like this:

```
var re = /L[0-9]+:[^;]+/g;
var test = 'Hello you have multiple L2:Me here;L3:Me not here; and some other text...';
var match = test.match(re);
console.log(match);
// match = ["L2:Me here", "L3:Me not here"]
```

Explanation:

- `L[0-9]+:` matches L followed by any sequence of numbers, followed by a colon (i.e. `"L105:"`)
- `[^;]+` matches any character that's not a semicolon (the `[^;]` part) at least once (the `+` part), and only stops once it reaches a semicolon
- The `g` flag makes the matches global, that is, to not just find the first match and stop

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but it should work

```
/(L\d:[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+;)/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is:

```
/L\d+:[^;]*/g
```

Meaning, begin with an `L`, followed by a sequence of one or more digits (`\d+`), a `:`, and a sequence of zero or more characters not including a `;` (`[^;]*`). The `g` on the end is for "global", and makes the regex apply to more than one occurence.

Use with match:

```
var parts = test.match(/L\d+:[^;]*/g);
```